# Accidentally deleted partition which holds Windows 10 loader

Tags: boot-partition

I deleted a partition by mistake on my Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot system. At startup, a grub menu displays and I can successfully boot Ubuntu but Windows 10 refuses to boot. Output of Boot Info Script is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23744291/) and screen shot of Gparted:

[image]

Is there any solution to this problem or I will have to do fresh installation of Windows 10?

Comment: Which partition did you delete? They all appear to be in use. Did you delete it and then merge the unallocated space with another partition? If you have written other data to the partition already, then you will not be able to recover it.  If you did not write new data to the partition, then you may be able to recover the old partition table using a program called testdisk (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). If the data on the lost partition is not especially important to you, it would be much safer and easier to give up on it and reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: I had deleted /dev/sda2 partition.  I have  changed onlyits label to sunil and nothing done else.  There is no data on this partition but bootmgr  of Windows 10.  It is very tedious to reinstall windows, updates and softwares.  I would be very grateful if there will be a short method.

Comment: What do you mean you "deleted `/dev/sda2`"? There is currently a partition at `/dev/sda2` and it contains an NTFS file system. Did you alter the partition table after deleting that one partition? Did you (re-)format any partitions?

Comment: The label has changed to sunil. Maybe I've done Reformat. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be able to recover the partition pretty easily with TestDisk.

- Install TestDisk on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install testdisk`.
- I would strongly recommend that you carefully read the [partition recovery documentation](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) on the TestDisk site before you attempt a recovery. The "Deeper Search" and "Partition Table Recovery" sections will be especially important in your situation.
- You will almost certainly need to run a Deeper Search when you Analyse the partition table.
- In the Deeper Search results, look for a partition that is the correct size (around 10.6 GB) and inspect its file list to verify that it is your Windows 10 partition.
- Once you have found the correct deleted partition, change it from Deleted to Primary
- Write the changes to the partition table and exit TestDisk

If everything went well, your Windows 10 partition should be recovered, and you should once again be able to boot into Windows.